# How to resolve frequent changes in latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps

In my application I write the code for fetching latitude and longitude of current location.  But it is frequently changing while my device is not moving.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The frequent changes are caused by the inherent inaccuracy of GPS. You can just dampen down the signal with a time-decaying average, look at the reported speed in the GPS signal (anything less than 5-10 km/h is suspicious) or look at other sensors (e.g. acceleration) to judge whether you're moving or not.

Comment: And maybe use HDOP to calculate what part of the coordinates is significant.